# Multiple cell type swift 4.2

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

**SOLVED: I just added 'for-in'**

I hope that somebody will help me.
How can I display cells with a different elements inside satisfying "sequence" order. The cells should be arranged in any order and any number of each custom cell. I mean that first cell should to show first item type, second cell - second item type, third cell - first item type, fourth cell - first item.
It depends on the sequence from json data.
I have a json file with next structure (check the sequence array, that what I need):

```
{
    "data": [{
            "name": "first item",
            "data": {
                "text": "first item"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "second item",
            "data": {
                "url": "picture.png"
            }
        }
    ],
    "sequence": ["first item", "second item", "first item", "first item"]
}
```

I created My class for json parsing and other methods:

```
class MyClass {
        private let jsonStr = "url adress"
        var items = [ModelItem]()
        var jsonData: Object!

        func jsonParsing(completionHandler: @escaping (([ModelItem], Error?) -> Void)) {

            guard let url = URL(string: jsonStr) else { return }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

                guard let data = data else { DispatchQueue.main.async {completionHandler([], error)}
                    return
                }
                do {
                    self.jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if let name = self.jsonData?.data[0].data.text {
                            let firstItem = FirstItemModel(text: name)
                            self.items.append(firstItem)
                        }

                        if let pictureUrl = self.jsonData?.data[1].data.url {
                            let secondItem = SecondItemModel(pictureUrl: pictureUrl)
                            self.items.append(secondItem)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {completionHandler(self.items, nil)}
                } catch {
                    print("Error serializing json:", error)
                }
                } .resume()
        }
    }
```

Struct for JSON:

```
struct Object: Decodable {

    let data: [ArrayModelData]
    let sequence: [String]
}
```

Enum for multiple cell types:

```
enum ModelItemType: String {
    case firstItem
    case secondItem
}

protocol ModelItem {
    var type: ModelItemType { get }
    var rowCount: Int { get }
    var sectionTitle: String  { get }
}

extension ModelItem {
    var rowCount: Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

UITableView methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].rowCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = items[indexPath.section]
    switch item.type {
    case .firstItem:
        ...
    case .secondItem:
        ...       
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: I don't get your question. Inside `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you configure cell, so you can decide there which one you want to display and control the order.

Comment: I mean that I get order from json file (second array). And I would like to be able to use 2 different cell types in the same tableview but in a random (or not) order. So the cells should be arranged in any order and any number of each custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to keep a separate variables holding the each type of items.

```
var one: [ItemA]?
var two: [ItemB]?
var seq: [Int] = [1,2,1,1]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return one.count + two.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
    var data: [Item]
    if seq[row] == 1 {
        data = one[row]
    } else {
        data = two[row]
    }
    // ..
}
```

All items `ItemA`, `ItemB` types can conform to a protocol say `Item`.

```
protocol Item {
}

class ItemA: Item {}
class ItemB: Item {}
```